# How to change the Key and Value in a list of dict in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Looking for an efficient python code to achieve the below functionality.

```
input_dir =[{'NAME': 'ABC', 'VALUE': 'USA'}, {'NAME': 'PQR', 'VALUE': 'EU'}]
expected_output= {'ABC': 'USA', 'PQR': 'EU'}
```

and i am using the below code.

```
out_key = ''
out_value = ''
output_dictionary = {}
for index, item in enumerate(input_dir):
   for key in item:
          if key == 'NAME':
                 out_key = item[key]
          elif key == 'VALUE':
                 out_value = item[key]
   output_dictionary[out_key] = out_value
print(output_dictionary)
```

Is there any efficient way to do this? Any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a one liner actually. Do a dictionary comprehension as follows.

```
In [209]: {d["NAME"]:d["VALUE"] for d in input_dir}
Out[209]: {'ABC': 'USA', 'PQR': 'EU'}
```

Comment: Perfect!! really simple solution compared to my lengthy code! Thanks. @C Panda

Answer (score 1):

I haven't yet tested the following code on a computer, but you should be able reduce your code with a lambda function and iterating through the input dictionary:

```
 f = lambda x: (x['NAME'], x['VALUE'])
output_dictionary = dict(f(i) for i in input_dir)
```

Hope that helps.